# How can i change value of factor w/ 2 levels

Tags: r

I have variable  labels which is described as factor w 2 levels (1,2). I need it to be boolean and i do not have any idea how to change it when it comes to envoirement tab. I have tried something like this but obviously it is not working :P

```
for (x in labels)
 {
  if(x == 1
  {
     x == TRUE
  }
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share a minimal example of your data. Also show expected output.

Comment: Yes someone was quick on the trigger especially since I don't think OP knows more than the basics.  Are you trying to do this @endrew? `labels <-  ifelse(labels == 1, TRUE, FALSE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can directly use the `==` on the `vector` and change it to a boolean

```
labels == 1
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

#### data

```
labels <- factor(c(1, 2, 2, 2, 1))
```

Comment: I've populated factor w/2 levels "1", "2": 1 2 2 2 1
and want to change it to TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE

Comment: @endrew If `labels <- factor(c(1, 2, 2, 2, 1)); labels == 1` gives the logical vector